# How to use Micrometer Gauge the correct way?

Tags: spring, prometheus, metrics, micrometer

Say I have an application where a REST API updates the price of a product.
I want to use a Micrometer Gauge to expose the new price as a metric. I'm having trouble understanding from Micrometer documentation how this should be accomplished.

The only `toDoubleFunction()` that worked for me was to create a new method in my `ProductService` which returns its price. This seems like an overhead for every piece of data I want to expose as a metric.

What am I missing here? Why `product.getPrice()` isn't enough to update the Gauge?

Comment: Please include your code that isn't working. The gauge could use `product.getPrice()` assuming it hasn't been garbage collected. More likely you'll want to cache the price in a map and drive the gauge using the map.

Answer (score 3):

Micrometer's `Gauge` would hold a reference to whatever it has to pull the value from. And that reference is a [`WeakReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) by default.

For example:

- [StatsdGauge](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/implementations/micrometer-registry-statsd/src/main/java/io/micrometer/statsd/StatsdGauge.java#L41)
- [DefaultGauge](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/internal/DefaultGauge.java#L45)

This means that should your provided value get garbage collected, micrometer would have nothing to poll the value from.

I assume that when you call `product.getPrice();` you never hold on to that value just passing it to something like `meterRegistry.gauge("product.price",tags,value);` Since after the completion of this block of code nothing holds a strong reference to that specific value it gets Garbage Collected (GC-ed).

You have couple solutions here: either build a `Gauge` using a builder and specifying the `strongReference(true)` or (better) make sure you hold your references and manage their values yourself.

Both are rather weird as you'll end up holding a lot of "Gauge sources" in memory.